# Search Bar not covering the whole navigation bar when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

The `UISearchBar` is not covering the whole `UINavigationBar` when tapped. This happens on iOS 7/8 on iPad (It works properly on iPhones). `TitleBar and BarButtonItems` are still visible in the background.

Following images are of a the `UISearchBar` set as a `HeaderView` of a `TableView`. The 
`TableViewController` is inside a `DetailView` of a `SplitViewController`.

[image]

[image]

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[searchBar setDelegate:self];
self.searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self.emptySearchTableView;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

Comment: `self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;`

Comment: Nope....does not solve the problem.